# Javascript url code won't trigger the bootstrap modal in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I added this link `https://website.test/about/contact-us/?modal=example` in wp backend menu editor and checked the link after I input this code that's supposed to open the bootstrap model once the link was entered in the browser. However it didn't work.

Here's my javascript code that I added within `<script>` at bottom under `</footer>` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {

$(document).ready(function() {
 if(window.location.href.indexOf('/?modal=example') != -1) {
   $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
 }
});

})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Every time I try to refresh or type the url in another page, it won't load/open the modal. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the url I was looking for turned out to be like this

```
https://website.org/about/contact-us?modal=example
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [URLSearchParams()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to check for the query param.

```
const params = new URLSearchParams(location.search),
      modal_param = params.get('modal'); 

if(modal_param){
  // do stuff
}
```